# module to show shipping methods on free product page?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, shipping-estimate

I need a module that looks for the user's zip code on the product page, does anyone know of a free module?

Answer (score 1):

please try this

https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-shipping-calculator-on-product-page.html

hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this module for this:
https://github.com/mageprince/Magento2-PincodeChecker

This module is used to check the availability of Pincode for products. You can also exclude pin codes by product. You can add, edit, update and delete pin codes by admin. You can also import the bulk of pin codes via a .csv file.